# XPath for first child element inside body tag

Tags: html, xpath

This is HTML code,

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <img src=""/>
</head>
<body>
     <p></p>
      <div>
           <img src=""/>
     </div>
     <img src=""/>
</body>
```

I need XPath for the first img element inside body tag. Anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/html/body/descendant::img[1]` for instance. That finds the first descendant `img`, for child elements only use `/html/body/img[1]`.